# Cloudera Hadoop MapReduce error: Task process exit with nonzero status of 65

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, pentaho, cloudera

I have Pentaho MapReduce job (basically Java job) which takes HBase data as map input. 
Workflow works perfectly for small amount of data (e.g. 100 rows of data) but fails when run on few hundred thousand of record. Two mapper jobs are submitted to cluster, and they are are doing simple aggregation of data (about 400 000 rows separated in two HBase regions).
It seams that task fails to reports it's status within 600 second what is regulated by mapred.task.timeout setting in mapred-site.xml. I'm not sure how to change this setting inside Cloudera 4.1.4 distribution of Hadoop? Also in following error log you can see some other errors:

```
Meta VERSION="1" .
Job JOBID="job_201309201413_0003" JOBNAME="hotel reviews agg HBase" USER="root" SUBMIT_TIME="1379684231747" JOBCONF="hdfs://HDP-MASTER\.PI\.LOCAL:8020/user/root/\.staging/job_201309201413_0003/job\.xml" VIEW_JOB="*" MODIFY_JOB="*" JOB_QUEUE="default" .
Job JOBID="job_201309201413_0003" JOB_PRIORITY="NORMAL" .
Job JOBID="job_201309201413_0003" LAUNCH_TIME="1379684231998" TOTAL_MAPS="2" TOTAL_REDUCES="1" JOB_STATUS="PREP" .
Task TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000003" TASK_TYPE="SETUP" START_TIME="1379684232152" SPLITS="" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="SETUP" TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000003" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201309201413_0003_m_000003_0" START_TIME="1379684232617" TRACKER_NAME="tracker_HDP-MASTER\.PI\.LOCAL:localhost/127\.0\.0\.1:47578" HTTP_PORT="50060" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="SETUP" TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000003" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201309201413_0003_m_000003_0" TASK_STATUS="SUCCESS" FINISH_TIME="1379684234634" HOSTNAME="/default/HDP-MASTER\.PI\.LOCAL" STATE_STRING="setup" COUNTERS="{(org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapreduce\.FileSystemCounter)(File System Counters)[(FILE_BYTES_READ)(FILE: Number of bytes read)(0)][(FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN)(FILE: Number of bytes written)(285100)][(FILE_READ_OPS)(FILE: Number of read operations)(0)][(FILE_LARGE_READ_OPS)(FILE: Number of large read operations)(0)][(FILE_WRITE_OPS)(FILE: Number of write operations)(0)][(HDFS_BYTES_READ)(HDFS: Number of bytes read)(0)][(HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN)(HDFS: Number of bytes written)(0)][(HDFS_READ_OPS)(HDFS: Number of read operations)(0)][(HDFS_LARGE_READ_OPS)(HDFS: Number of large read operations)(0)][(HDFS_WRITE_OPS)(HDFS: Number of write operations)(1)]}{(org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapreduce\.TaskCounter)(Map-Reduce Framework)[(SPILLED_RECORDS)(Spilled Records)(0)][(CPU_MILLISECONDS)(CPU time spent \\(ms\\))(180)][(PHYSICAL_MEMORY_BYTES)(Physical memory \\(bytes\\) snapshot)(143708160)][(VIRTUAL_MEMORY_BYTES)(Virtual memory \\(bytes\\) snapshot)(739024896)][(COMMITTED_HEAP_BYTES)(Total committed heap usage \\(bytes\\))(200998912)]}nullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull" .
Task TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000003" TASK_TYPE="SETUP" TASK_STATUS="SUCCESS" FINISH_TIME="1379684234879" COUNTERS="{(org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapreduce\.FileSystemCounter)(File System Counters)[(FILE_BYTES_READ)(FILE: Number of bytes read)(0)][(FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN)(FILE: Number of bytes written)(285100)][(FILE_READ_OPS)(FILE: Number of read operations)(0)][(FILE_LARGE_READ_OPS)(FILE: Number of large read operations)(0)][(FILE_WRITE_OPS)(FILE: Number of write operations)(0)][(HDFS_BYTES_READ)(HDFS: Number of bytes read)(0)][(HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN)(HDFS: Number of bytes written)(0)][(HDFS_READ_OPS)(HDFS: Number of read operations)(0)][(HDFS_LARGE_READ_OPS)(HDFS: Number of large read operations)(0)][(HDFS_WRITE_OPS)(HDFS: Number of write operations)(1)]}{(org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapreduce\.TaskCounter)(Map-Reduce Framework)[(SPILLED_RECORDS)(Spilled Records)(0)][(CPU_MILLISECONDS)(CPU time spent \\(ms\\))(180)][(PHYSICAL_MEMORY_BYTES)(Physical memory \\(bytes\\) snapshot)(143708160)][(VIRTUAL_MEMORY_BYTES)(Virtual memory \\(bytes\\) snapshot)(739024896)][(COMMITTED_HEAP_BYTES)(Total committed heap usage \\(bytes\\))(200998912)]}nullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull" .
Job JOBID="job_201309201413_0003" JOB_STATUS="RUNNING" .
Task TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000000" TASK_TYPE="MAP" START_TIME="1379684235791" SPLITS="/default/HDP-SLAVE1\.PI\.LOCAL" .
Task TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000001" TASK_TYPE="MAP" START_TIME="1379684235792" SPLITS="/default/HDP-SLAVE2\.PI\.LOCAL" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="MAP" TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000000" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201309201413_0003_m_000000_0" START_TIME="1379684235797" TRACKER_NAME="tracker_HDP-MASTER\.PI\.LOCAL:localhost/127\.0\.0\.1:47578" HTTP_PORT="50060" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="MAP" TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000000" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201309201413_0003_m_000000_0" TASK_STATUS="FAILED" FINISH_TIME="1379684420508" HOSTNAME="HDP-MASTER\.PI\.LOCAL" ERROR="java\.lang\.Throwable: Child Error
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.TaskRunner\.run(TaskRunner\.java:250)
Caused by: java\.io\.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 65\.
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.TaskRunner\.run(TaskRunner\.java:237)
" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="MAP" TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000001" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201309201413_0003_m_000001_0" START_TIME="1379684235798" TRACKER_NAME="tracker_HDP-MASTER\.PI\.LOCAL:localhost/127\.0\.0\.1:47578" HTTP_PORT="50060" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="MAP" TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000001" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201309201413_0003_m_000001_0" TASK_STATUS="FAILED" FINISH_TIME="1379684918509" HOSTNAME="HDP-MASTER\.PI\.LOCAL" ERROR="Task attempt_201309201413_0003_m_000001_0 failed to report status for 600 seconds\. Killing!" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="MAP" TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000000" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201309201413_0003_m_000000_1" START_TIME="1379684420613" TRACKER_NAME="tracker_HDP-MASTER\.PI\.LOCAL:localhost/127\.0\.0\.1:47578" HTTP_PORT="50060" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="MAP" TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000000" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201309201413_0003_m_000000_1" TASK_STATUS="FAILED" FINISH_TIME="1379685147302" HOSTNAME="HDP-MASTER\.PI\.LOCAL" ERROR="Task attempt_201309201413_0003_m_000000_1 failed to report status for 600 seconds\. Killing!" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="MAP" TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000000" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201309201413_0003_m_000000_2" START_TIME="1379685147358" TRACKER_NAME="tracker_HDP-MASTER\.PI\.LOCAL:localhost/127\.0\.0\.1:47578" HTTP_PORT="50060" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="MAP" TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000000" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201309201413_0003_m_000000_2" TASK_STATUS="FAILED" FINISH_TIME="1379685300867" HOSTNAME="HDP-MASTER\.PI\.LOCAL" ERROR="org\.apache\.hadoop\.io\.SecureIOUtils$AlreadyExistsException: EEXIST: File exists
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.io\.SecureIOUtils\.createForWrite(SecureIOUtils\.java:178)
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.TaskLog\.writeToIndexFile(TaskLog\.java:303)
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.TaskLog\.syncLogs(TaskLog\.java:376)
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.Child$4\.run(Child\.java:270)
    at java\.security\.AccessController\.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax\.security\.auth\.Subject\.doAs(Subject\.java:396)
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.security\.UserGroupInformation\.doAs(UserGroupInformation\.java:1332)
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.Child\.main(Child\.java:262)
Caused by: EEXIST: File exists
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.io\.nativeio\.NativeIO\.open(Native Method)
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.io\.SecureIOUtils\.createForWrite(SecureIOUtils\.java:172)
    \.\.\. 7 more
" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="MAP" TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000000" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201309201413_0003_m_000000_3" START_TIME="1379685300874" TRACKER_NAME="tracker_HDP-MASTER\.PI\.LOCAL:localhost/127\.0\.0\.1:47578" HTTP_PORT="50060" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="MAP" TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000000" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201309201413_0003_m_000000_3" TASK_STATUS="FAILED" FINISH_TIME="1379685525375" HOSTNAME="HDP-MASTER\.PI\.LOCAL" ERROR="org\.apache\.hadoop\.io\.SecureIOUtils$AlreadyExistsException: EEXIST: File exists
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.io\.SecureIOUtils\.createForWrite(SecureIOUtils\.java:178)
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.TaskLog\.writeToIndexFile(TaskLog\.java:303)
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.TaskLog\.syncLogs(TaskLog\.java:376)
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.Child$4\.run(Child\.java:270)
    at java\.security\.AccessController\.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax\.security\.auth\.Subject\.doAs(Subject\.java:396)
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.security\.UserGroupInformation\.doAs(UserGroupInformation\.java:1332)
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.Child\.main(Child\.java:262)
Caused by: EEXIST: File exists
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.io\.nativeio\.NativeIO\.open(Native Method)
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.io\.SecureIOUtils\.createForWrite(SecureIOUtils\.java:172)
    \.\.\. 7 more
" .
Task TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000000" TASK_TYPE="MAP" TASK_STATUS="FAILED" FINISH_TIME="1379685525375" ERROR="org\.apache\.hadoop\.io\.SecureIOUtils$AlreadyExistsException: EEXIST: File exists
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.io\.SecureIOUtils\.createForWrite(SecureIOUtils\.java:178)
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.TaskLog\.writeToIndexFile(TaskLog\.java:303)
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.TaskLog\.syncLogs(TaskLog\.java:376)
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.Child$4\.run(Child\.java:270)
    at java\.security\.AccessController\.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax\.security\.auth\.Subject\.doAs(Subject\.java:396)
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.security\.UserGroupInformation\.doAs(UserGroupInformation\.java:1332)
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.Child\.main(Child\.java:262)
Caused by: EEXIST: File exists
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.io\.nativeio\.NativeIO\.open(Native Method)
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.io\.SecureIOUtils\.createForWrite(SecureIOUtils\.java:172)
    \.\.\. 7 more
" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="" .
Task TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000002" TASK_TYPE="CLEANUP" START_TIME="1379685525619" SPLITS="" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="MAP" TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000001" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201309201413_0003_m_000001_1" START_TIME="1379684918586" TRACKER_NAME="tracker_HDP-MASTER\.PI\.LOCAL:localhost/127\.0\.0\.1:47578" HTTP_PORT="50060" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="MAP" TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000001" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201309201413_0003_m_000001_1" TASK_STATUS="KILLED" FINISH_TIME="1379685525643" HOSTNAME="HDP-MASTER\.PI\.LOCAL" ERROR="" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="CLEANUP" TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000002" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201309201413_0003_m_000002_0" START_TIME="1379685525630" TRACKER_NAME="tracker_HDP-MASTER\.PI\.LOCAL:localhost/127\.0\.0\.1:47578" HTTP_PORT="50060" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="CLEANUP" TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000002" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201309201413_0003_m_000002_0" TASK_STATUS="SUCCESS" FINISH_TIME="1379685529379" HOSTNAME="/default/HDP-MASTER\.PI\.LOCAL" STATE_STRING="cleanup" COUNTERS="{(org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapreduce\.FileSystemCounter)(File System Counters)[(FILE_BYTES_READ)(FILE: Number of bytes read)(0)][(FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN)(FILE: Number of bytes written)(285100)][(FILE_READ_OPS)(FILE: Number of read operations)(0)][(FILE_LARGE_READ_OPS)(FILE: Number of large read operations)(0)][(FILE_WRITE_OPS)(FILE: Number of write operations)(0)][(HDFS_BYTES_READ)(HDFS: Number of bytes read)(0)][(HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN)(HDFS: Number of bytes written)(0)][(HDFS_READ_OPS)(HDFS: Number of read operations)(1)][(HDFS_LARGE_READ_OPS)(HDFS: Number of large read operations)(0)][(HDFS_WRITE_OPS)(HDFS: Number of write operations)(2)]}{(org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapreduce\.TaskCounter)(Map-Reduce Framework)[(SPILLED_RECORDS)(Spilled Records)(0)][(CPU_MILLISECONDS)(CPU time spent \\(ms\\))(190)][(PHYSICAL_MEMORY_BYTES)(Physical memory \\(bytes\\) snapshot)(135462912)][(VIRTUAL_MEMORY_BYTES)(Virtual memory \\(bytes\\) snapshot)(739024896)][(COMMITTED_HEAP_BYTES)(Total committed heap usage \\(bytes\\))(200998912)]}nullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull" .
Task TASKID="task_201309201413_0003_m_000002" TASK_TYPE="CLEANUP" TASK_STATUS="SUCCESS" FINISH_TIME="1379685529548" COUNTERS="{(org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapreduce\.FileSystemCounter)(File System Counters)[(FILE_BYTES_READ)(FILE: Number of bytes read)(0)][(FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN)(FILE: Number of bytes written)(285100)][(FILE_READ_OPS)(FILE: Number of read operations)(0)][(FILE_LARGE_READ_OPS)(FILE: Number of large read operations)(0)][(FILE_WRITE_OPS)(FILE: Number of write operations)(0)][(HDFS_BYTES_READ)(HDFS: Number of bytes read)(0)][(HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN)(HDFS: Number of bytes written)(0)][(HDFS_READ_OPS)(HDFS: Number of read operations)(1)][(HDFS_LARGE_READ_OPS)(HDFS: Number of large read operations)(0)][(HDFS_WRITE_OPS)(HDFS: Number of write operations)(2)]}{(org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapreduce\.TaskCounter)(Map-Reduce Framework)[(SPILLED_RECORDS)(Spilled Records)(0)][(CPU_MILLISECONDS)(CPU time spent \\(ms\\))(190)][(PHYSICAL_MEMORY_BYTES)(Physical memory \\(bytes\\) snapshot)(135462912)][(VIRTUAL_MEMORY_BYTES)(Virtual memory \\(bytes\\) snapshot)(739024896)][(COMMITTED_HEAP_BYTES)(Total committed heap usage \\(bytes\\))(200998912)]}nullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull" .
Job JOBID="job_201309201413_0003" FINISH_TIME="1379685529549" JOB_STATUS="FAILED" FINISHED_MAPS="0" FINISHED_REDUCES="0" .
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that job tracker cannot communicate with task tracker.

May be the task is too heavy.